# tomcat ajp connector with multiple webapps

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat, ajp

I have a tomcat server, with a webapps/ROOT application, fronted by Apache.

```
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
```

and

```
  ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
  ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
```

I need to add a second webapp to this box, so I unpacked it into webapps/pib.war/ and changed the Apache conf:

```
  ProxyPass /pib http://localhost:8009/pib
  ProxyPassReverse /pib http://localhost:8009/pib
  ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
  ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
```

My tomcat/conf/server.xml contains:

```
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
             resourceName="UserDatabase" />
      <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" />
    </Engine>
  </Service>
```

I have only one context.xml file - there are none under the webapps - in conf/context.xml

```
<Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>
```

When I visit https://myserver/ then the existing, default, ROOT application works as normal, but https://myserver/pib/ gives, in catalina.out:

```
org.apache.jk.common.MsgAjp processHeader
SEVERE: BAD packet signature 18245
```

which the intertubes suggest means I'm talking HTTP to the AJP connector, instead of AJP, yet the first webapp is working properly.

What am I missing?  I've seen mention of context.xml files under each webapp, but I'm not sure what they're *for* or what to put in them.

I don't normally use AJP, but this box is already working that way, so I'm a little lost right now.

Thanks,

Comment: Why did you add the second application (pib) with `http` protocol in Apache proxy directives (`ProxyPass`/`ProxyPassReverse`) instead of `ajp`?

Comment: do you need to add the other one? Doesnt the first take care of forwarding everything to tomcat? i am not very sure hence the question...

Comment: ivantod: oh, dear, spot on.  I stared and stared at those lines and didn't see that.  How embarrassing.  Thank you.  I had changed it from AJP connector to HTTP connector and it was all working, now I can go back to AJP.  *shamefaced*